# "Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace"

Tags: apache

Where and how do I exactly enable LogLevel debug? I have absolutely no knowledge of Apache, it's a miracle I found out this much. My site gives a "500 internal server error" and I'm trying to fix that.